# Double quote escaping for valid JSON

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a string say - `this is a "string that needs" escaping"`. This string ultimately gets saved in a JSON object so the double quotes must be escaped properly.

I've implemented a utility function to escape it -

```
export function escapeJsonString(str) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
  return str.replace(/"/g, '\"');
}
```

The output form this is exactly what I need - `this is a \"string that needs\" escaping`. However, eslint complains that the escape character is useless?

Is there a better way to do this while ensuring I am compliant with ESLint? I'd prefer not to turn off this rule.

Comment: In your case, ESLint means, that `'\"'` has a useless ecape char. However, you probably meant `'\\"'`, which really inserts a backslash in the string. BTW, it sounds like you have an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/428538) Could you tell us, why do you need to do what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case, you can do this.

```
'this is a \\"string that needs\\" escaping'
```

ESLint does not complain about this.

Comment: Well, I would also need to unescape the double quote then since my UI renders this text as - `\"string that needs escaping\"`